# ggplot2, how can I change the position of strip labels or add a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I created a pair of bar plots using facet_grid in ggplot2.  I have customized everything as I like except the strip labels.  I figured out how to turn off the strip labels using strip.text.y = element_blank(), and I can move the labels to the left side of the chart (switch).  However, neither are satisfactory.  I would like the labels placed at the top or to make a legend.  If I can get them to the top of each plot I would probably want to remove teh strip background and justify the position of the text, say to the right side of each plot.  I found a reference to a strip.position element but it did not work for me.

I tried strip.position but could not get it to work.  In fact strip.position did not appear as an option when typing in code in R studio.

### Create dataframe

```
cage<-c(3:11)
sage<-c(2:8,10,12:16)
Age<-c(cage,sage)
c<-rep("Choptank",9)
s<-rep("Severn",13)
River<-c(c,s)
n<-c(2,35,19,4,1,52,4,3,2,1,2,39,11,5,2,57,2,1,3,4,2,2)
B<-data.frame(River,Age,n) %>% 
group_by(River,Age) %>% 
tally() %>% 
mutate(prop=n/sum(n))
```

### Theme for bar plots

```
bartheme<- theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines"),
axis.line = element_line(size = 1,colour = "black"),
axis.title = element_text(colour="black",
size = rel(1.5)),
plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14),
plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=14),
panel.background = element_rect(fill="whitesmoke"),
axis.text = element_text(colour = "black",
size = rel(1)))
```

### Faceted bar plot, 1 stacked over the other

```
Bplot <- ggplot(data = B,
aes(x = Age, y =prop))+ 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 
position_dodge(),fill="dodgerblue")+
geom_text(aes(label=round(prop,2)), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
facet_grid(rows=vars(River))+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), oob=rescale_none,expand=c(0,0))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))

Bplot+bartheme+ggtitle("Age distribution of white 
perch")+ylab("Proportion")
```

I obtain the stacked plots as expected with strip labels on right side of each plot (text vertical).  I would prefer strip labels placed at the top of each plot - preferably with some control over appearance.

Comment: Fantastic.  I guess my problem was facet_grid.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Now, If I want to lower the stripe labels slightly so they fit inside the plot (still at top), is that a vjust adjustment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout of facets can be more finely controlled using `facet_wrap` and you can control the appearance of facet labels using the theme elements prefixed by `strip`. See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) for details.

Here is an example with your data that places the labels on top of the graphs and removes the shading, plus right justifies the text. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are a looking for but it should give you the tools to adjust to your liking.

```
bartheme <- theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                  panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines"),
                  axis.line = element_line(size = 1,colour = "black"),
                  axis.title = element_text(colour="black", size = rel(1.5)),
                  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14),
                  plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=14),
                  panel.background = element_rect(fill="whitesmoke"),
                  axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = rel(1)),
                  strip.background = element_blank(),
                  strip.text = element_text(hjust = 1)
)

Bplot <- 
  ggplot(data = B, aes(x = Age, y = prop)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(), fill = "dodgerblue") +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(prop, 2)), vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) +
    facet_wrap(vars(River), ncol = 1) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), oob=rescale_none,expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))

Bplot + bartheme + ggtitle("Age distribution of white perch") + ylab("Proportion")
```

Comment: I would also recommend looking at the R cookbook by Winston Chang (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/)

Comment: Thanks so much!  Works great.  I have looked but could not find an answer if I can tweak the position of the strip labels.  In this instance they are right justified at the top and sit above each plot.  Can I shift them down slightly to fit within the plots themselves, while still being in the upper right corners?  If not it is ok, this will work.   Thanks again.

Comment: Great - please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer if it is working for you. To have labels actually within the plot itself I think you might have to use `geom_text` instead of the facet labeller. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178610/moving-the-strip-labels-on-a-facet-wrapped-graph-to-the-interior-of-each-graph).